# Unwrapping dictionary values Swift

Tags: swift, nodes

I'm creating an adjacency list in Swift, storing an array of nodes. However, when adding an edge from an existing node I need to check if the from key exists in any of the children, and if it does check if the to value exists in the same. It seems to be a mess s.t.

```
func addEdge(from: String, to: String) {
//the full code for addEdge is incomplete here
    if (children.contains{ $0.nodes[from] != nil}) {
    for child in children {
        if (child.nodes[from] != nil) {
            if (!(child.nodes[from]?.contains{$0 == to})!){
                child.nodes[from]?.append(to)
            }
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Children is

```
var children = [Node]()
```

and Node is

```
class Node: Hashable {
    var nodes = [String:[String]]()
    var hashValue: Int{ return nodes.hashValue }
    static func == (lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
        return lhs.nodes.keys == rhs.nodes.keys
    }
}
```

Now it works, but seems really ugly. There must be a better way in Swift, but what is it?

Comment: You could just change your `var nodes = [String:[String]]()` to be a structure instead where the `from` & `to` are typed properties. Your `Node` class needs to have those properties and then your `nodes` will be `var nodes = [Nodes]()`.

Comment: Won't lookups be slower?

Comment: No. Absolutely not. You will even be able to drop your nil checking and introduce optional binding with `while var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you do not wish to change the way you have implemented the above code but want to improve readability, you can utilise `if let` and optional chaining to make your code cleaner and more readable.

```
func addEdge(from: String, to: String) {
//the full code for addEdge is incomplete here
    if children.contains{ $0.nodes[from] != nil } {
        for child in children {
            if let fromNode = child.nodes[from], fromNode.contains{$0 == to} {
                fromNode.append(to)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Swift Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
if (children.contains{ $0.nodes[from] != nil}) {
    children.filter { $0.nodes[from] != nil }.
       compactMap { $0.nodes[from] }.
       filter { !($0.nodes[from]!.contains{$0 == to}) }.
       forEach { $0.nodes[from]?.append(to) }
}
```